# Working with U.S. date and time and Incrementing

Tags: java

I want to create a function that takes in a string representing a date in the format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm AM or PM" and I want to increment days and time X number of times before it is returned in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm AM or PM". Right now the only way I know of is to convert it to European date and time, work with it using LocalDateTime or Calendar and then convert it again, but it feels inefficient converting back and forth. Are there any date and time objects that can work with US time and do things like increments?

Comment: You could just parse/format it from/to `LocalDateTime` directly....

Comment: The only efficient way is representing your date and time as `LocalDateTime` internally in your program (not as strings). The cost of parsing your input and formatting your output is very small compared to the advantages of using a proper date and time type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimeFormatter + LocalDateTime

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("05/06/2020 3:45:00 PM", formater);
dateTime.plus(5, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...)` to parse your string to a LocalDateTime. There are also options for parsing AM/PM

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking in the date as a String in the first place you will need to do a conversion to LocalDateTime to manipulate it. That being said, you could do something like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatter("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse([yourString], formatter);
```

From here you would do your date/time manipulation using the plus and minus methods from this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html
Then once you have done that create a SimpleDateFormat like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormatter.ofPattern(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a)
```

and then print your string like so:

```
sdf.format(date).toString();
```

Comment: Please note , that for multi-threaded applications you need to synchronize when  SimpleDateFormat is used.

Comment: It seems you've mixed up different things such `SimpleDateFormat` created with constructor and `DateTimeFormatter` created via `ofPattern`.  Also, sdf won't print `LocalDateTime` instances.